# How send variable to WebApi controlleri using session or other solution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a "database reference" with a table with these information

1. Company name
2. Company Code
3. Connection string

Each company has his own connectionstring to access his own database. Then I have x databases (same structure), one by company.

I have to do this :

1. Get some information from query string to access "database reference"
2. Access "database reference" to get the connection string
3. I have to send this connection string or the repository constructor via DI (Unity)

I tough use session variable (I know about state less), but I don't want to keep anything between 2 calls.

I founded several solution with application variable but in my case it's not the right way.

Via a filter attribute but in this case I have to be able to send value from attribute to the controller, but the constructor is called before.

Could you help me for this ?

Thanks,

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, DbRefernceAdministrationContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, CompanyContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(new CompanyContext()));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all the database connection string info to app.config.

Then pick database ref from query string by

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DbRefApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{databaseref}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Get active connection string by

```
public string GetActiveConnString()
{
   //Read from app.config file 
   //create an active repository using connection string 

}
```

Comment: I know I can do this. But there are connectionstring and much more other stuff